# dll file reference not working in client computer vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I have added `zkemkeeper.dll` reference in vb.net application. It is working in my computer but when i try to run in client computer it does not work. I copied and paste `zkemkeeper.dll` in system32 folder  and also in same folder where `exe` file is located but still it is not working.
When i try to open the form of vb application which contain zkemkeeper class it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `zkemkeeper.dll` is unmanaged, COM dll. You probably have to register it using regsvr32.dll. It doesn't matter where it resides, as long as you register it. Would be helpful if you would post the error you get.

And yes here is exactly what you asked for http://www.zktechnology.eu/index.php/faq-category/sdk/registering-sdk

How to use regsvr32.dll http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873

Comment: I am wondering, if it only took me 10 seconds to find the answer, why the person who asked couldn't do it?

Comment: thanks for your reply but i even tried that you said. I try to register using regsvr32 it is also showing error

Comment: @user3324681 So, you need to post everything you've done. Because your question doesn't reflect that and we have no idea what error you get. On the issue, you may not registering it properly for the architecture you got. So please post everything. Otherwise you will not get help here and your question will be deleted

Comment: I am having problem in client computer. so i need to access my client computer for detail about error which is quite impossible now. I will post it tommorrow. I will be thankful if you wait till tommorrow.